# Programmatically determine the size of an iPad modal view

Tags: ios, ipad, modal-dialog

I've got an iPad application which presents a modal view. I'd like to do some programmatic manipulation of the modal view's controls, but I can't find the way to get the modal view's size. If I call View.Bounds or View.Frame it gives me the bounds/frame for the whole screen (i.e. 1024x768) - but I know from measuring myself that the modal view is actually about 540x620.

While I know I can hard-code this in myself, this makes me feel dirty... is there a programmatic way for a modal view to get its own 'real' size?

Thanks

John

Comment: can you post the code for what you're doing to get it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking - I'm trying to find out what the code is to get the size, I don't have it written already...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks. The problem was actually that I was trying to get the size in the ViewDidLoad method, rather than ViewDidAppear (that one always gets me...). In ViewDidLoad it was returning the 1024x768 size, but when I moved my code into ViewDidAppear, it started returning the correct (540x620) size!

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried setting `modalPresentationStyle`?

```
modalController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
```

Then you should get the correct frame size (540 x 620) from `modalController.view.frame`.

Comment: Thanks. The problem was actually that I was trying to get the size in the ViewDidLoad method, rather than ViewDidAppear (that one always gets me...). In ViewDidLoad it was returning the 1024x768 size, but when I moved my code into ViewDidAppear, it started returning the correct (540x620) size!

Comment: @John This comment of yours made me realize why I often had issues with getting and setting the view's size. I guess this info is written somewhere in the apple doc too. Anyway, I think you should have created an answer (since that's what it is) instead of writing a comment.